# xtables-addon installation failed

Tags: kernel, security, iptables

I have a server with ubuntu 12.04 and when I try to install xtables-addon with this command `module-assistant auto-install xtables-addons-source` I get this error

```
Bad luck, the kernel headers for the target kernel version could not be found and you did not specify other valid kernel headers to use.
If the running kernel has been shipped with the Debian distribution, please install the package linux-headers-3.2.13-grsec-xxxx-grs-ipv6-64. If your kernel
 source tree (or headers) is located in some non-usual location,please set the KERNELDIRS environment variable to the path of this directory, or (alternatively) specify the source directory
 we build for with the --kernel-dir option in module-assistant calls.
```

If I run uname -r I get this :

```
3.2.13-grsec-xxxx-grs-ipv6-64
```

I think that my host have modified the installed kernel ubuntu .

How can I fix this ?

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

This how I fixed this issue :

change the source to default from [here](http://www.howtoforge.com/perfect-server-ubuntu-12.04-lts-apache2-bind-dovecot-ispconfig-3-p3)

```
apt-get update
apt-get install linux-image-server
cd /etc/grub.d/
mv 06_OVHkernel /root/
update-grub
reboot
apt-get install linux-headers-`uname -r`
```

insiperd from this [link](http://wiki.artica.fr/index.php/VirtualBox%3a_Unable_to_start_Virtual_Machines_on_OVH_servers)